# Bing Maps V8 - How to create connecting/repeated polylines

Tags: javascript, windows, bing-maps

I need to draw continues polylines between different locations available on two different map. Lets say we are in panorama view and currently a complete world map is visible. Now if we will slide the map to the left side then we will get another world map and so on. Please see below explanation showing connecting polylines between two different maps.

```
       Map#1                              Map#2                       Map#3 ::
```

New York----Amsterdam----Shanghai----New York----Amsterdam----Shanghai----New York

Hope this image will give you better understanding. Thanks
[Image showing connecting polylines across the different maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbxP0.png)

Comment: Are you using multiple map controls? As V8 will only ever display a single map at a time.

Comment: Yes I'm using V8. At a time its displaying single map but we can slide the map left/right to see the another map. Lets say at a time I can see half part of one map and half part of another map. Thanks.

Comment: It's the same map, it wraps around. It's like spinning a globe. The Bing Maps team is working to make lines follow the shortest path between points which currently doesn't work when a path crosses the anti-meridian (-180/180 longitude)